# Stretch InlineUIContainer to take 100% of the RichTextBlock's width?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, richtextblock

I've got a simple `InlineUIContainer` inside a `Paragraph`, inside a `RichTextBlock`. How can I make the content inside the InlineUIContainer take the full width of the RichTextBlock? Setting the `HorizontalAlignment` property obviously does nothing, so what can? For the moment I'm using the *extremely* hacky way of having:

```
<RichTextBlock>
    <Paragraph>
         <InlineUIContainer>
             <TextBlock Text="__________________________________________________________________" FontSize="72"/>
             <!--Content-->
         </InlineUIContainer>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

This is obviously an extremely bad way of getting it to stretch, so what would work?

Answer (score 0):

[InlineUIContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents.inlineuicontainer) can't stretch to take whole width of the `RichTextBlock`. Ref [**Remarks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents.inlineuicontainer#remarks) of [InlineUIContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents.inlineuicontainer):

> Setting properties on [InlineUIContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents.inlineuicontainer) that otherwise affect the character line height of a text element (such as [FontSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents.textelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_Documents_TextElement_FontSize), [FontFamily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents.textelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_Documents_TextElement_FontFamily) ) has no effect on the rendering and appearance. **The content dictates its size and the [InlineUIContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents.inlineuicontainer) sizes to fit it.**

So the width of `InlineUIContainer` is controlled by its content not its parents. If you want `InlineUIContainer` to take 100% of the `RichTextBlock`'s width, I'm afraid you have to use some "hacky" way to provide a wide enough content for `InlineUIContainer`.